# Python CSV Write column

Tags: python, csv, file-io

I got this sample code:

```
import csv
w = csv.writer(file(r'test.csv','wb'), dialect='excel')
some_values=[(1,2,3)]
w.writerows(some_values)
```

When I open the CSV in excel, I got all values in same `column(A)`. I want to put values in `A1`, `B1` and `C1`. How can I do that?

MS Office Excel 2007 SP2

Thank you.

**SOLUTION:**

w = csv.writer(file(r'test.csv','wb'), delimiter=';')

Comment: One second: Are you perhaps using a non-US version of Excel? Because for example German Excel uses `;` as a separator, Python's `excel` dialect delivers commas.

Comment: You're right! I add this flag, delimiter=';'. Thank you.

Comment: @user1073911 - I am not sure if you are already allowed to answer your own question or not, but as soon as you can you should write your solution as an answer and select it as accepted, so other visitors will know at a glance this question got solved. You should even get a bronze badge for that, I believe...

Comment: Users with less than 100 reputation need to wait 8 hours after the question is asked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

w = csv.writer(file(r'test.csv','wb'), delimiter=';')

Answer (score 2):

I've never used the CSV module before, but you're setting some_values to a list of tuples.

So the first element of the list is a tuple (1,2,3).

Should you be usingjust a list [1,2,3] or a tuple (1,2,3)?

Comment: I thought that too at first, but since he's using writerows I imagine it's expecting an iterable of iterables.

Answer (score 0):

Each value needs to be a member of a list, not tuple: 

e.g. `w.writerows([1, 2, 3])`. 

In this example, 1 - 3 get written into separate columns.